# covert kodak PNG images into JP2 with sampling factor

Tags: jpeg, image-compression, jpeg2000

I am trying to convert png images into JP2 with sampling factor. I am using imagemagick tool for conversion, as they mentioned in docs -sampling-factor is used for sampling but it did not work.
http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/unix/graphics/ImageMagick/www/jp2.html

```
convert wizard.png -colorspace YUV -sampling-factor 2,2 wizard.jp2
```

My command, it did not work

```
convert test/images/kodim$i.png -quality $(($j*5)) -colorspace YUV -sampling-factor 4,2 test/JP2/kodim$i/`printf "%02d" $j`.jp2
```

Comment: Suggest you post your issue to the ImageMagick GIT forum at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick

Comment: @fmw42 Already posted. Waiting for response